# How to keep Makefile running but still maintain the error code?

Tags: makefile

This is my current code

```
  .PHONY: setup-kind
  setup-kind:
      -eksctl get cluster integ-clus
      ([ $$? -eq "0" ] && echo "cluster exists") || echo "cluster does not exist"
```

This cluster does not exist so I expect "cluster does not exist" to be printed. The command(eksctl get cluster integ-clus) will fail because the cluster doesn't exist but the Makefile will keep running because i added a '-'  to the start of the command(Ignore error)

The issue is that then the status of the command becomes a '0' because of my ignore addition and "cluster exists" will be printed as a result.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can approach this and get the code to execute the "cluster exists" block/logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common beginner error. Out of the box, every line in a `make` recipe executes in a separate subshell; the second line has no idea what happened in the first.

In this case, there is absolutely no reason to use two lines, anyway.

```
.PHONY: setup-kind
setup-kind:
    eksctl get cluster integ-clus \
    && echo "cluster exists" \
    || echo "cluster does not exist"
```

(The backslashes escape the newlines, so this is logically a single line.)

The result will be the exit code from either of the `echo`s, so there is no need for a leading minus any longer.

Perhaps see also [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

By design, `make` will abort the current recipe if a command fails, so there is no well-defined way for a recipe to return a nonzero exit code and not abort the `make` or ignore the error result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found a cleaner solution(listing all the clusters and getting the size of that) and checking that against 0.

Comment: You're welcome (though there's another common antipattern lurking there, see [useless use of `wc`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc).)